# Embedding YouTube live stream in android application

Tags: android, iframe, webview, youtube

I'm embedding youtube live stream using webview in my android app. I'm using `iframe` for the same. Is there a way i can set the size of video player according to screen size.

```
 public class WebViewPlayer extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view_player);

        String frameVideo = "<html><body>Youtube video .. <br> <iframe width=\"400\" height=\"290\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=UCYn0pQcA8IMxk4cDFzlBF2w&autoplay=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"true\"></iframe></body></html>";

        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the iFrame that worked for me. You just have to pass the `layout_width` of the `webview` as `match_parent` and a fix `layout_height`. The iFrame contains a script as well you can remove that if it is not required. Let me know if this is helpful for you.

**Iframe**

```
"<html><body style='margin:0px;padding:0px;'><script type='text/javascript' " +
"src='http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api'></script><script type='text/javascript'>" +
"function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(){ytplayer=new YT.Player('playerId'," +
"{events:{onReady:onPlayerReady}})}function onPlayerReady(a){a.target.playVideo();}"+
"</script>Youtube video .. <br><iframe id='playerId' type='text/html' width='100%' height='100%' " +
"https://www.youtube.com/embed/live_stream?channel=UCYn0pQcA8IMxk4cDFzlBF2w&autoplay=1' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></body></html>"

webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: Actually my code is not playing the video at all :( I'm just getting a blank white screen

Comment: @PrashantLuhar I have edited the answer. You can user `loadDataWithBaseUrl` instead of `loadData`. This is working for me, if not working for you then i will share something else.

Comment: `loadDataWithBaseUrl` is not working as well :\ I don't know whats the error.

Comment: @PrashantLuhar Actually `webview` is all about trial and error. Try adding this `webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this player to play live YouTube videos in your Android app: [android-youtube-player](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player).

It is equivalent to using the IFrame player in a WebView, but nicer.

[Here](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player#live-videos) is the documentation about live videos.

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to use [YouTubePlayerView](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView)

Comment: YouTubePlayerView doesn't support live stream. I tried it. The video code of live stream keeps changing so it cannot be used